# How to assign constant to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to assign an address value to a pointer, but I get this `warning`:

```
#define PRODUCT_NUMBER_ADDR  0x12345

"foo\foo.c", line 1444: cc1967: {D} warning: "long *" pointer set to
          literal value - volatile needed?
              ram_address = (long*) (PRODUCT_NUMBER_ADDR);
                                     ^
```

How can I properly assign my address to my pointer?

Comment: The compiler is likely warning you that `ram_address` is not volatile, which is usually needed when reading a ram address that the hardware itself updates (which is usually what you're doing when assigning a literal address to a pointer). Regardless, it's just a warning; the code should still compiler.

Comment: This question would be more useful if you'd provide a minimal working example. While some folks have been quite successful at guessing what your code would be based on the shown error message, it would be more useful (to future readers) to see the actual code in the question.

Comment: If you have hardware registers, using built-in types is a bad idea. Use `stdint.h` types, e.g. `uint32_t` instead (unsigned versions strongly recommended).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
ram_address = (long*) (PRODUCT_NUMBER_ADDR);
```

to

```
ram_address = (volatile long*) (PRODUCT_NUMBER_ADDR);
```

Also make sure `ram_address` is declared as a `volatile long *`. Using `volatile`  here tells the compiler the memory object can have its value changed unexpectedly and so the compiler should not make any cacheing assumption.